# How do I add a new component to the screen from another screen in React Native/Navigation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

I'm relatively new to React/Native/Navigation as a whole and I'm creating my first app. As the title says, I do not know how I could possibly add a new component to the screen from another.

A button in Screen A, please ignore the one above "Get global variable":

[image: A button in Screen A, please ignore the one above "Get global variable"]

What I would like to do is to be able to add another button below it, when a function is called from another screen.

For example, in Screen B, I have a button that says "Confirm", that is what will add the *first* button into Screen A. By pressing "Confirm" multiple times, I would like to add more buttons onto Screen A.

I am not sure if this is possible, nor the way to do it. Reading through the documentation has not helped me thus far.

For reference, this the code for "Confirm"

```
  <Button 
    title="Confirm" 
    onPress={() => {
      navigation.navigate({
        name: 'ScreenB',
        params: { 
          placeholder: box("placeholder"),
        },
        merge: true
      });
    }}
    />
```

Comment: That's where state management comes to play. You can use a Context that both screen A and B have access to or use a state management library like Mobx-State-Tree or Redux.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to store how many times the user clicked on Confirm button in screen B and then while navigating to screen A you can pass that value as navigation parameter and then read that value in screen A. Then simply display that number of Buttons in Screen A.